# How to retrieve images from API in Uniconta

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to retrieve images when using the regular API for Uniconta: https://www.uniconta.com/da/developers-unipedia/api/

When I query it, for inventory items, or userdocs, the image tag is empty, even though we have uploaded images for the item.

Comment: Does Uniconta provide support?

Comment: Yeah, but paid support only, also requires that you are a paying customer.

Comment: Did you add fields? https://www.uniconta.com/developers-unipedia-global/api-global/user-defined-fields/

Comment: @jdweng i did not add any fields, I'm using it as is, out of the box. 
I've uploaded the image to a product, and now can't retrieve the image from either the product, or through the UserDocsClient

Comment: Can yoiu retireive data tha is not images?

Comment: Ye all data that is strings do i have no problem receving at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a api.Read(your UserDocsClient object)

This should fill _data property.